# Blender closes when rendering smoke in preview

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, error

I started to create smoke according to Blender Guru tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-zK7Bu8cAI. I made a circle mesh and added quick smoke to it and after that, I tried to render preview with Shift + Z and Blender crashed without any error. I use experimental mode in Blender 2.78 but toggling it has no impact, it still crashes. I also tried toggling between CPU and GPU, still no effect. What seems to be a problem? Without smoke, it renders fine. [image: Smoke]

Comment: Tried cube and added to it quick smoke. Still, crash. The circle isn't the point. When you add to it quick smoke it shows  only wireframe even if it filled with a face.

Comment: How many faces there are in the scene? Did you try to render it in a simple scene with 2 dummy cubes? What about toggling on the console window and looking into it if there are any errors before crash? If it renders fine without smoke likely it can be too few resources for the volume rendering.

Comment: it has only 44k faces.

Comment: Try a recent daily build from the build bot. Maybe it's a bug that's already fixed. https://builder.blender.org/download/